# boost::multi_index_container crashes with _com_ptr_t objects

Tags: c++, boost

I try to use `boost::multi_index_container` with _com_ptr_t objects.
Code compiles with no warnings but crashes in runtime.
Standard containers (`std::set`, `map` etc) work perfectly with such objects.

Is it possible to use multi_index_container with _com_ptr_t?

Sample code here:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost\multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\global_fun.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\ordered_index.hpp>

#import "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll" exclude("ISequentialStream", "_FILETIME")

using CTest = 
  boost::multi_index_container<MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr, 
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::random_access<>>>;


int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(nullptr);

    CTest tst;

    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr doc;
    doc.CreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument);

    tst.push_back(std::move(doc)); <-- crash here

    ::CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you get a crash without std::move (assuming doc is copyable)?

Comment: Looks to me it is boost::move that causes the problem.  "Suitably instrumented" is too vague to stick a fork into.  So no.

Comment: That's what I saw when single-stepping the code.  Boost 1.55

Comment: Yes, I get a crash without std::move.

tst.push_back(doc); - also crashes

Answer (score 2):

- I notice that the `multi_index_container` you've defined holds pointers of type `MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr`, yet `doc` is of type `MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr` (without the `2`). I'm assuming this is OK, as the problem is really not related to this discrepancy.
- Boost.MultiIndex [does support move semantics](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/release_notes.html#boost_1_55), so you can use `std::move` as you please.
- The actual problem is that `_com_ptr_t` has a weird, destructive [`operator&` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803e9tsc.aspx) returning a pointer to the wrapped interface. This confuses  the internal code of Boost.MultiIndex. You can easily bypass this overload as follows:

```
#include <boost\multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\global_fun.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\ordered_index.hpp>

#import "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll" exclude("ISequentialStream", "_FILETIME")

struct IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr:MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr
{
  using MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr;

  IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr* operator&(){return this;}
  const IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr* operator&()const{return this;}
};

using CTest = 
  boost::multi_index_container<IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr, 
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::random_access<>>>;

int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(nullptr);
    {
        // defined in scope so that destruction happens before CoUninitialize
        CTest tst; 

        MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr doc;
        doc.CreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument);

        tst.push_back(std::move(doc));
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

- Would you mind entering a ticket for this problem at [Boost Trac](https://svn.boost.org/trac)? I can fix the issue internally (by not relying on user-overloadable `operator&`s) but it's going to take a while till I find the time to do so and I wouldn't like to forget about it.

**Postscript**

If you have this problem throughout your program, you can automate the fix as follows:

```
#include <boost\multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\global_fun.hpp>
#include <boost\multi_index\ordered_index.hpp>

#import "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msxml6.dll" exclude("ISequentialStream", "_FILETIME")

template<typename CComPtr>
struct CFixedAddressofComPtr:CComPtr
{
  using CComPtr::CComPtr;

  CFixedAddressofComPtr* operator&(){return this;}
  const CFixedAddressofComPtr* operator&()const{return this;}
};

template<typename CComPtr,typename TIndexList>
using CComPtrMultiIndexContainer=boost::multi_index_container<
  CFixedAddressofComPtr<CComPtr>,
  TIndexList
>;

using CTest = 
  CComPtrMultiIndexContainer<MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr, 
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::random_access<>>>;

int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(nullptr);

    {
        // declared in scope so that destruction happens before CoUninitialize.
        CTest tst; 

        MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr doc;
        doc.CreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument);

        tst.push_back(std::move(doc));
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tinkering with operator& like this is pretty dangerous, it will cause a memory leak due to the missing IUnknown::Release() call.  Looks weird, but it was written to expect the programmer to use it in, say, a QueryInterface call, a common coding pattern.

Comment: Do you mean my tinkering or `_com_ptr_t`'s tinkering? Either way please note that the user-defined `IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr` class is only used inside the `multi_index_container` to circumvent the problem: the rest of the app can happily continue to work with `MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr`.

Comment: Thank you for workaround. But I can't use it. It's only sample. In real code I have a lot of such _com_ptr_t-wrappers for COM-interfaces. Ticket at [Boost Trac already exists](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13307)

Comment: Added a way to automate the workaround in case it's useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for help. I already wrote the similar workaround.
But I would prefer transparent fix in boost::multi_index, because it should be used in large project with many developers.